# Python create a new mail. Return Line (\n) in body not working

Tags: python, html, outlook

I'm working on a python script which should create a new mail with a specific text body.

Fact is that **`\n`** does not work as excepted.

My code is below :

```
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = "This is a return line test \nTest"
```

The body displayed is :

```
This is a return line test Test
```

And not :

```
This is a return line test 
Test
```

What Am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `HtmlBody` , instead of `\n`, you want to use the HTML style tags for your new-lines. These are called line-breaks, and they look like this: `<br>`. So you want to replace `\n` with `<br>`:

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = recipient
mail.Subject = subject
mail.HtmlBody = "This is a return line test <br>Test"
```

Answer (score 2):

*The new line **`\n`** character doesn't work on **`.HtmlBody`** instead use `mail.Body`*

*Example*

```
mail.Body = "This is a return line test \nTest"
```

*[HTMLBody Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa171418(v=office.11))*

> *Returns or sets a String representing the HTML body of the specified item. The HTMLBody property should be an HTML syntax string*

*Or you could use **`<pre>`** tag set to recognize newlines in **`HTML`***

*Example*

```
mail.HTMLBody = "<pre>This is a return line test \nTest</pre>"
```

*https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp*